# Testing a spring bean which has a reference which not defined in the same module

Tags: spring

We have a module A which depends on module B. Module B has spring bean class B1 that has a reference to bean A1 located at module A. Module B also have bean of class B2 with no references. 
Our main class is at module A,so we can load the application context from there with no priblems. But, we have also unit test at module B that test class B2. So - the unit test loads application context of module B. That's makes the unit test failed to load application context since it has also now bean of class B1 which has a reference on class on module A.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

If B2 doesn't need B1 or A, then just load that single class in your unit test with `@ConfigurationContext(classes= B2)`

Comment: Class B2 has a constructor with argument which defined as a bean in application-context of module B. So I have to load application-context of module B....